# check for empty group and remove it from array

Tags: angular, filter

I have array of projectName and users. which i filter for searching value inside dropdown options. so requirement is that i have my filter value but i also have empty projectNames in which the search value doesn’t Exist and i want to show only array which has searched users name.

```
groups: [{
 projectName: xyz,
 users:[{user1}, {user2}]
},
{
 projectName: abc,
 users:[{user1}, {user2}]
}
]
```

my search is by name so if i have serchValue 'abc' than user 'xyz' is empty but the project Name is Still there so i want to remove the whole group is search doesn’t match.

i hope someone help me. Thank You

Comment: Just do something like `groups = groups.filter(item => item.projectName)`

Comment: i already have filter function applied on group.users.filter('here i return user in custom filterfunction').

Comment: What is preventing you from applying it again?

Comment: i did apply nothing preventing me but it didn’t work.

Comment: could you please provide little more info , as i understand u have multiple filters used already please provide code

Comment: Without knowing what do you want to do, it's hard to spot your problem. But I can suggest something and you can comment and we get there afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you need to clean up undesired users and wrong project names. I suggest you first filter project names, so you'll have less users to check:

```js
groups = groups.filter(g => g.projectName);
```

Now, for each project, you want to filter users with a special role, for example, a fictitious 'manager' role:

```js
groups = groups.filter(g => g.projectName);
groups.forEach(g => g.users = g.users.filter(u => u.roles.includes('manager'));
```